# Tweet (or facebook) status update from iPhone with predefined Text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, twitter

Hey, 
sorry to bother you again, but I can't get this to work and would appreciate a *working* example project.. I try to give my users the possibility to post a short, predefined message from inside my App on either twitter or facebook (both should be available, but it doesn't have to update both on the same action, so one button to "share on facebook", one button to "tweet about it", so if you have a solution for facebook, but not for twitter or vice versa, I'd happily take the solution you have, either facebook or twitter and go on searching for the other one). It's my first time trying to interact with facebook and twitter, so I need something like dummy-proof explanation.

I found MGTwitterEngine but it seems to be hell to get it working. I've found Ben Gottlieb's Twitter OAuth-iPhone bundle, inserted my data, "registered" my app, and stuck with a gray screen on my device.

I'd need a working example of an iPhone App Project, that manages to tweet or update the facebook status of a user (maybe after a short and painless(!) login). Than I'd happily fiddle around myself to get this working, but by now I only find links to Desktop-Applications, examples or demos that won't work out of the box, or expect you to have done this several times before -.-

Thanks for your help, and sorry if that is an easy question, but I can't find the answer I need..

Comment: MGTwitterEngine is really good for Twitter. Try to get it work, I also have the same difficulty at first, but it worked after some time.

Comment: Can you get it to work with *any* text? I mean - not predefined, but taken from the user?

Comment: @Abizem No, I stuck with the demo already. I manage to get Ben Gottlieb's Demo to work, but after register my App through that interface the screen stays gray, no matter what I do. I have absolutly no idea how that should be setup :/

Comment: @fatih You don't happen to have a demo/example project you could share? To see which files need to be added and how to call the functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to be able to publish to a number of different services is [ShareKit](https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit). This supports sending messages to Twitter, Facebook and a bunch of other services.

Comment: agreed. Just use ShareKit. Getting your head around oauth and the likes is no piece of cake. Just use their solution!

Comment: Darlington I've read about ShareKit and got some code from their site, but when I add it into an HTML and display the HTML in a UIWebView, the Webview stays blank (was working before). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but as it uses javascript, do I have to add this somehow too? I'm not really familiar with js, and never ever tried to use it with an iPhone App.

Comment: ShareKit is Objective C code, not HTML or JavaScript, so it seems unlikely that adding it to your project would "break" your web view -- unless you added it incorrectly. The instructions are on the website I linked to and look pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed things up! I've read about "ShareThis", tried it, and they provide JS Code. Thanks, ShareKit is awesome! It worked almost immediately!